# Prevent windows from queuing shellexecute requests

Tags: winapi, vb6

```
Win.ShellExecute 0, "open", "C:\dir\program.exe", "arguments", vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL
Win.ShellExecute 0, "open", "http://www.google.com", vbNullString, vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

I want google.com to open regardless of whether or not program.exe is still running.  How do I fix this? I would rather avoid things like calling "start."

Both of these calls happen pretty much instantly, and the VB program continues running.  However, on both Vista and XP, google.com does not open until program.exe closes.  If the application which called `shellexecute` closes before program.exe closes, google.com will still open once program.exe is closed.

Note:

I have found that having program.exe call doevents every 100ms or so fixes the problem, but obviously this is somewhat of a hack.

Note2:
Below is an example implementation of program.exe.  Yes, I realize that changing program.exe will fix this (i.e. adding a `doevents` call).

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub Main()
    Do Until False
        Sleep 100
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Does passing a valid HWND as the first parameter make any difference?

Comment: @tyranid: The test application doesn't even use forms.

Comment: Then that maybe be part of your issue, I assume program.exe doesn't display any user interface either?

Comment: @tyranid: True.  However, the only way that relates to the problem is that if program.exe used a UI, it would end up giving its message pump a chance to handle events (which would solve the problem in the same way manually calling doevents solves it).  However, your discussion misses the point: I want to solve the problem by not having program.exe handling the events from the google.com shellexecute at all, not by making sure program.exe actually handles the events.  The latter solution I already know how to do, as I mentioned.

Comment: @tyranid: I changed my test program to have a GUI, and passed its hwnd to shellexecute.  This made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to use CreateProcess instead?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the Process API rather than ShellExecute

```
Private Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, lpProcessAttributes As Any, lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
      hProcess As Long
      hThread As Long
      dwProcessId As Long
      dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
      cb As Long
      lpReserved As String
      lpDesktop As String
      lpTitle As String
      dwX As Long
      dwY As Long
      dwXSize As Long
      dwYSize As Long
      dwXCountChars As Long
      dwYCountChars As Long
      dwFillAttribute As Long
      dwFlags As Long
      wShowWindow As Integer
      cbReserved2 As Integer
      lpReserved2 As Long
      hStdInput As Long
      hStdOutput As Long
      hStdError As Long
End Type
```

If you need to halt until it is done you this

```
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
```

The code to use look something like this

```
ReturnValue = CreateProcess(NullString, AppPathString, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&, 1&, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, ByVal 0&, NullString, StartupInformation, ProcessInformation)
Do While WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInformation.hProcess, 0) <> 0
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I *don't* want to wait until it is done, rather than that I do.

Comment: Then don't use Waitforsingleobject. I put that up there to lay out all the common options with using the Process API. Once you execute CreateProcess the other application start running and CreateProcess returns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the intrinsic [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(VS.60).aspx) to launch Program.exe, rather than ShellExecute? (I'm assuming `Win.ShellExecute` is the API call of the same name - you could include the declaration in your question.)

Also, `tyranid` is right that giving your application a form may solve the problem. I've had odd behaviour from VB6 apps with no forms.

Comment: @Markj: The "real" app does have a form.  And the ideal is to fix it without changing program.exe.

Comment: Good idea.  I tried using both a shell32.shell object and calling the shell function.  The former behaves the same and the latter, your suggestion, blocks completely until the program exits, which is even worse.

Comment: GIving my test application a form had no effect.